# Charge distribution in a conducting sphere

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus, physics, partial-derivative

This is a math problem that appeared in a physics one:

"Evaluate the density of electrical charge in the surface of a hollow sphere such that the electric field is constant (in direction and absolute value) inside of it."

I wonder if this can be solved by using Leibniz's Rule for integration.

First let's supose the field points towards the same direction of the $x$- axis in the usual $R^3$ ($\vec {i}$ direction) the plane $yz$ is perpendicular to the field so it is an equipotential surface. Therefore the solution of the problem does not depend on $\theta$  since the charge density must be equal on every point of the intersection of the plane with the sphere.

:[image: point inside the ball]

So:

$d\vec{E} =\frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon} \frac{(\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P))dq}{(||\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P)||)^3}$

$\vec{E} = \frac{1}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sigma (\phi) R^2 \sin(\phi)(\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P)) d\theta d\phi}{||\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P)||^3} $

$\vec{E} = \frac{R^2}{4\pi\epsilon} \int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi} \frac{\sigma (\phi) \sin(\phi)(\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P)) d\theta d\phi}{||\vec r(\theta, \phi) - \vec r(P)||^3} $

where

$\vec r(\theta,\phi) = R(\cos(\theta)\sin(\phi), \sin(\theta)\sin(\phi), \cos(\phi))$

$\vec r(P) = (x_p,y_p,z_p)$ , $x_p^2 + y_p^2+z_p^2 < R^2$ is a constant vector

Is this solvable by using the Leibniz rule for integrals ?

$\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial x_p} = 0$

$\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial y_p} = 0$

$\frac{\partial \vec{E}}{\partial z_p} = 0$

Comment: Are you sure you want to solve this with explicit integration? I'm fairly certain there is a geometric solution.

Comment: I'm really curious about the integration method, but now I want to see the geometric also, can you please show me ?

Comment: @Ian you can't come here, tell me there is an elementary geometric solution and go away!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!